# Applying simple text to a picture API in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I am developing a telegram bot that involves the process of adding a text that the user input to an existing image.

It goes like that:

1. The user inputs a text like his name, time, etc.
2. The bot adds a text layer on top of the image. (the image is constant and doesn't change).
3. The user gets in return from the bot the picture with the added text, in a typical image format like JPG or PNG (doesn't matter).

However I actually have no idea what kind of method or API I should use, I was thinking of something like photoshop API but it seems way too complicated and overkill. I am looking for a simple solution that is easy to learn and apply, as it is just adding a text layer on top of a picture and saving it.

I would be interested to hear how would you apply such a thing, to get ideas on how it could be done.

Thank you very much,
Shay

Comment: That depends on the programming language you want to use?

Comment: I don't think it depends here, I am looking for some kind of API that is available for free. Some kind of photo editing API which I send parameters and get in return the editied picture. I have found pho.to but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: If I were you, I'd do the job with the programming language itself, I assume most of them have libraries to work with images. That's why there are only a few APIs out there. I found [imagix](https://docs.imgix.com/apis/url)